# Determine which server is the best choice for high resource-consuming task

Tags: ssh, cpu-usage

I have a time and resource consuming task I am running every once in a while (`make`), which can be run on any one of a servers pool.

Problem is, I am not the only user running `make`, and when two or more unaware users run `make` simultaneously, it takes forever, and sometimes the server even crashes.
So we decided that whenever someone wants to run `make`, he or she must first `ssh` into one of the servers, make sure `make` is not already running on it by other user (using linux's `w`), and only then does he or she start `make`.

In my attempts to automate the process of choosing a server, I wrote a simple script, that loops on the servers pool, `ssh` into every one of them, and chooses the first server for which the output of `w` has no `make` in it, but this approach is too naive because it ignores the following:

- Each server has different attributes (e.g. one with 12 CPUs, and the other with 80 CPUs)
- `make` is not the only task that these servers run
- `w` only shows processes of users that are logged through `ssh`, and while `make` is run using `ssh` most of the time, it may well be that someone is running `make` from the server itself.

I want to change the criteria for choosing a server, but not sure what it should be.
I looked online and found the `top` command, but again, I am not sure what should be considered.
For example, I thought about using the criteria: `$(top -bn 1 | grep 'Cpu\(s\)' | gawk '{print $2+$3+$4+$6+$7+$8}')` to determine which one is the least busiest right now, but this ignores the server's attributes. There could be a busier server with considerably more CPUs.

Comment: this sounds like a task for a job scheduler like [torque](http://www.adaptivecomputing.com/products/open-source/torque/) or [slurm](http://slurm.schedmd.com/).  or maybe something like [distcc](http://distcc.org/) (and see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/distcc).  BTW, all of these are packaged for debian and ubuntu and probably most other distros too.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for a distributed task/job scheduler, cluster management system, or cloud management. A lot of these already exist; cas pointed to several in his comments and Google will turn up plenty more.

I suspect you all will be much happier once you've deployed one, and no longer have to worry about stepping on each others' toes all the time. Also, you should fix your servers so that mistakes just cause the task to fail, not bring down the machine.

If you insist on building your own (something I confess I've done—though it was 15 years ago), tasks broadly speaking consume several different types of resources, and you probably want to consider which ones your tasks take:

- memory (RAM) [from your goes really slow or crashes, I'd guess this is a big one for your `make` task]
- disk I/O bandwidth
- disk I/O operations per second (seeks)
- disk space
- CPU time
- GPU time
- network bandwidth

You can check memory usage via `free`, disk I/O via `iostat`, space with `free`, CPU usage via `cat /proc/loadavg` (on Linux) or `uptime`, `top`, `ps`, etc.

But of course, checking the current numbers has a problem—maybe your `make` job first does a few simple things taking a few minutes, then fires off the huge process that takes gigs of RAM. This could happen:

1. Alice runs the script to start a "make" task.
2. Script checks serverA, sees it has tons of free RAM, low CPU usage, starts task on serverA.
3. Short while later, Bob runs the script to start some other RAM-intensive task.
4. Alice's task hasn't gotten to the resource intensive phase yet. So when the script checks serverA, it still has tons of free RAM. Starts Bob's task on serverA as well.
5. Bob's task eats up most of the free RAM on serverA
6. Alice's task finally gets to the RAM-intensive part, but there is no RAM available now. Uh-oh! ServerA thrashes to death.

Yeah, the above comes from experience writing one (though for what I was using mine for, it was CPU time).